# Efficient way to find numbers that multiply to given numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I'm given `2` lists, `a` and `b`. Both them contain only integers. `min(a) > 0`, `max(a)` can be upto `1e10` and `max(abs(b))` can be upto `1e5`. I need to find the number of tuples `(x, y, z)`, where `x` is in `a` and `y, z` are in `b` such that `x = -yz`. The number of elements in `a` and `b` can be upto `1e5`.

My attempt:

I was able to come up with a naive `n^2` algorithm. But, since the size can be upto 1e5, I need to come up with a `nlogn` solution (max) instead. What I did was:

1. Split `b` into `bp` and `bn` where the first one contains all the positive numbers and second one contains all the negative numbers and created their maps.
2. Then:

   2.1 I iterate over `a` to get `x`'s.

   2.2 Iterate over the shorter one of `bn` and `bp`. Check if the current element divides `x`. If yes, use `map.find()` to see if `z = -x/y` is present or not.

What could be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Does the value of `z` have any meaningful limitations?

Comment: Perhaps you could factorize `x` to obtain all of its prime factors. If there is only one, then only `y = a, z = 1` is a solution. If there are two or more, you would have to search through all pairs of factors `x0, x1` where `x0*x1 = x` and find those like you already do in step 2. At least this way, you don't just brute-force all values of `a` (of which there can be many).

Comment: @NO_NAME The only constraint is that it'll be in the range `-1e5` to `1e5`

Comment: @J.Schultke - I was sketching out a similar solution.  I'm also wondering if would make sense to factorize elements from set `b` instead of from `a` since there are only 20000 possible elements in the latter set.

Comment: @J.Schultke I thought about that. But, it takes `O(sqrt(n))` time to prime factorise `n` (at least by the algo I know). Since `n/x` can be `1e10`, its root still gives me `1e5`, which I think should be somewhat equivalent to iterating over b

Comment: @J.Schultke Factorization isn't a particularly fast algorithm. It may allow to create a faster solution but only if lists `a` and `b` are very big.

Comment: @selbie not sure if it's a typo, but there can be 200000 possible elements (2e5)

Comment: Yes, but far less than `10000000000`.

Comment: Another possible optimization.  If `x` is odd, then both `y` and `z` must be odd.  If `x` is even, than at least one of `y` and `z` must be positive.

Comment: Maybe there is some pattern between originating from the way they are generated. This could help to make some heuristics. Sorry, I don't have a better ideas. Maybe, in the meantime, try benchmarking the algorithm based on factorization.

Comment: you can create ```map``` hash-container for ```a```, ```map[a[i]] = true```, as I understand ```b``` can be positive and negative, so you can sort the array by quick sort. therefore you can find "neutral" element  - first positive number after negative or zero. After you can use nested for-loop to multiple numbers (external loop with only negative numbers, internal with only positive), the result of multiplication is used to check is there this result in map ```map[b1*b2] == true```

Comment: More: you can use nested for-loop to check a rest of ```a[i] % b[j]```, if it's zero, then add it in ```map_a_array_for_negative[a[i]] ++ ``` and ```map_a_array_for_positive[a[i]] ++ ``` , so you'll get two map containers and multiply each element and sum everything it at the end

Comment: @AyratArifullin It's very similar to what I did. The complexity still remains `O(n^2)`

Comment: One more point :) Theoretically, you can calculate multiplication of all ```b``` elements like ```M = b[0]*b[1]*...*b[N-1]```, right? This is ```O(n)```, therefore you can check ```M % a[i] == 0?``` But indeed you have memory restrictions however on this idea you can base something similar

Comment: @AyratArifullin `b` can have `1e5` elements, and they can be as large as `1e5`. You can't multiply these numbers, will lead to overflow

Comment: This smells like it should be [3SUM-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM).

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Sort the elements in list `b` (say `bsorted`)
- Step 2: For a value `x` in `a`, go through the list `bsorted` for every value y in `bsorted` and binary search for (-x/y) on `bsorted` to find z

Complexity |a|=m and |b|=n complexity is O(mnlogn)

Answer (score 1):

There's no O(n*logn) because: `z = -x/y` <=> `log(z) = log(-x) - log(y)`

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299000/kaya3 has mentioned, it is [3SUM#3_different_arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#3_different_arrays). According to wikipedia:

> Kane, Lovett, and Moran showed that the 6-linear decision tree complexity of 3SUM is O(n*log^2n)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested idea. Create a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from the elements of `b`, where the "characters" are ordered prime numbers. For each element in `a`, walk all valid paths in the trie (DFS or BFS, where the test is being able to divide further by the current node), and for each leaf reached, check if the remaining element (after dividing at each node) exists in `b`. (We may need to handle duplicates by storing counts of each "word" and using simple combinatorics.)